# Compartilhar internet via wifi utilizando linha de comando

Tags: windows, redes

Tenho um adaptador wifi, ou poderia ser um notebook, e compartilho a internet via Wifi, não é esse o problema, segue abaixo como faço para criar uma rede wifi:

> **Criar uma rede wifi**
>
> 1. Acessar o CMD como administrador;
> 2. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=nomeHost key=senha`
> 3. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
>
> Com esses passos deixo a rede wifi para se conectar, e para dar acesso
>   a internet pela rede, acesso o  painel de controle > rede e internet >
>   Conexão de rede.
>
> Depois disso, nas propriedades de rede via cabo, a padrão,
>   geralmente "Ethernet", na aba compartilhamento, selecionar a primeira e
>   segunda opção, e na Conexão Domestica selecione a conexão local que
>   foi criada pelo comando, geralmente "Conexão Local*", algo assim.

**Problema:**
Gostaria de executar os passos de compartilhamento via linha de comando, pois algumas vezes durante o dia preciso reiniciar, pois simplesmente, para de funcionar.

Se alguém pelo menos souber o que posso usar, algum componente do windows. Não quero programas que façam isso por mim, quero eu mesmo fazer.

Comment: Pra mim esta pergunta é fora do escopo, pois ela tem mais a ver com configuração de sistema operacional do que rede propriamente dito.

Comment: @Articuno, [leia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  "um algorítmo de software" o windows por ser um SO, logo é um software, então é está dentro do escopo.

Comment: Pra mim é uma pergunta válida, usar linha de comando significa que é possível usar código, programas para realizar as operações (como por exemplo usar um script php para compartilhar um wifi), imagine que estou programando um servidor pré-pago de wifi para uma instituição por exemplo.
Além disso acredito que  cabe a reflexão nos argumentos do Gabe:
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com

Comment: Isso é programação Shell Script, para mim é dentro do scopo, mas sabe como é :)

Comment: no propiá wikipedia já pode te ajudar https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script @David

Answer (score 3):

Antes de saber o que é um script em shell, é importante saber o [que é um Shell.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script)

Você vai ter que criar um arquivo do tipo *.bat e adiciona esses comandos no arquivo:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=nomeHost key=senha
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

no inicializar do windows, isso vai depender da versão do windows que vc está utilizando, [Como executar automaticamente um arquivo BAT ao ligar o computador](http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/executar-arquivo/700045/)

Todas as coisas que vc quer fazer de conectar compartilhar e enxergar rede você pode adicionar os comandos nesse arquivo *.bat
[Como criar um arquivo batch](http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/arquivo-batch/272016/).

Comment: Vocês podem dar -1 mas tenho certeza que minha resposta ajudou o autor da pergunta :)

Comment: Acho que as dúvidas do AP são justamente sobre quais comandos ele deve colocar dentro do arquivo.